# Missing File Errors in Package Manager Console

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

Several members of our development team have started seeing the following errors when they open the Package Manager Console. It's completely preventing us from running Entity Framework commands. We've checked and the files mentioned do exist (`GetEvent.types.ps1xml`, `Diagnostics.Format.ps1xml`, `Diagnostics.Format.ps1xml`). We've tried restarting and cleaning the solution, but these don't seem to help. Has anybody encountered this before? Any ideas about how to fix it?

[image: Package Manager Console Missing Files Error]

Comment: it seem to be those Microsoft xml powershell script files are deleted or  damaged! you might have a virus or a problem in your  computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the latest Windows Management Framework release. An updated package has been released with a fix for this issue.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/24/windows-management-framework-wmf-5-0-rtm-packages-has-been-republished/