# VS2017 - Errors when opening Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual studio 2017 and then I try to open the package manage console I get this error.

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\GetEvent.types.ps1xml'.
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Diagnostics.Format.ps1xml'.
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Diagnostics.Format.ps1xml'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975127/missing-file-errors-in-package-manager-console

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated package that can be found...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/24/windows-management-framework-wmf-5-0-rtm-packages-has-been-republished/

Fix the issue for me.

Comment: Just tried, but did not get installed because it was already installed in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

This link gave me the solution to the above errors

Installing Powershell 5 on Windows 7 breaks Nuget Visual Studio package manager consoles
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3165

This fixed these errors as well:

```
    Could not add all required packages to the project. The following packages failed to install from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages':
NewtonSoft.Json.6.0.4 : Failed to initialize the powershell host.If your powershell execution policy is set to allsigned, open the package manager console to initialize the host first.
```

To check the power shell version:
Open PS > $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

I had version 5.0.
I updated to PS 5.1 and fixed the issues.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616